# Insert Into SomeTable Exec StoredProcedure @Param1 = @param1, @Param2 = 'system' is not calling Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where I need to run a stored procedure individually as well as I need to call from some other stored procedure.

Let me present the scenario: I have 3 stored procedures in sequential call from another one. Like 1st stored procedure is getting called from the application when some raw financial data is being imported; 2nd stored procedure is getting called from 1st stored procedure and in 2nd stored procedure, there is a `While` loop in which my 3rd stored procedure is getting called.

I am posting here 2nd and 3rd stored procedure code here:

2ND stored procedure code:

```
If @loopCount > 0
Begin
    While(@i <= @loopCount)
    Begin
    
        Select  @RecoString = '',
                @CompanyId = 0,
                @UserId = 0
    
        Select @RecoString = MainRecord, 
               @CompanyId = CompanyId,
               @UserId = UsersId
        From #RecoData With (Nolock)
        Where Id = @i
        Order By Id
        
        /* 3rd stored procedure is getting called - IF NO INSERT Statement */
        ----Exec USP_Temp @IsReco = 1,@ReconcileBy = 'system',@UserCompanyId = @UserCompanyId,@UserId = @UserId,@finalCollection = @RecoString

        /* 3rd stored procedure is NOT getting called - IF INSERT Statement */
        Insert Into dbo.ReconcileInsertUpdateLog(TransferDetailId,Msg,ReconcilationId,IsFutureTransferReconciled)
        Exec dbo.USP_Temp @IsReco = 1, @ReconcileBy = 'system', @CompanyId = @CompanyId, @UserId = @UserId, @finalCollection = @RecoString, @isAutoReconcile = 0
        
        Set @i = @i + 1

    End
End
```

3RD stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.USP_Temp
     @IsReco                    Bit
    ,@ReconcileBy               Nvarchar(250)
    ,@UserCompanyId             int 
    ,@UserId                    int
    ,@finalCollection           Nvarchar(Max) = ''
    ,@isAutoReconcile           Bit = 0
AS
BEGIN

    Set Nocount On;

    Declare  @TransName Varchar(100)
    
    Select  @TransName = 'USP_Temp'

    Begin Try
        
        Begin Transaction @TransName

        Declare  @Msg                           Nvarchar(Max) = ''
                ,@ParentReconcilationId         Int = 0             -- 07.25.2019
                ,@IsFutureTransferReconciled    Int = 0             -- 07.25.2019

        ------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Return result
        ------------------------------------------------------------

        Insert Into dbo.TempReco(Comments) 
        Select 'Reached to USP_Temp 1 step ahead of Return final Result'

        Select   1 As TransferDetailId
                ,@Msg As Msg
                ,@ParentReconcilationId As ReconcilationId                  -- 07.25.2019
                ,@IsFutureTransferReconciled    As IsFutureTransferReconciled   -- 07.25.2019

        Commit Transaction @TransName
        GoTo EndLevel

    End Try
    Begin Catch
    
        Set @Msg = Error_Message()
        GoTo Error

    End Catch

Error:
BEGIN
    Insert Into dbo.TempReco(Comments) Select 'Reached to USP_Temp - Error Block'
    Rollback Transaction @TransName
    Select   0 As TransferDetailId
            ,@Msg As Msg
            ,0 As ReconcilationId               -- 07.25.2019
            ,0 As IsFutureTransferReconciled        -- 07.25.2019
END
EndLevel:
END
GO
```

Look at the 2nd stored procedure code, I have commented the code which is working if no insert into statement prior to `Exec SPName` and when calling stored procedure along with insert into SomeTable prior statement then stored procedure is not getting called. Does anyone have some idea on this?

Comment: *"If No insert Statement while calling 3rd SP then SP is getting Called but If Insert Statement then it stopped getting called."* I'm sorry, but I don't follow what that means. What do you mean by there is no `INSERT` while calling the procedure? Do you mean that the Procedure returned no results, and thus no rows were effected by the `INSERT` statement? If so, you can see that by inspecting `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Comment: @Larnu, look at the 2nd SP code, I have commented the code which is working If No Insert Into Statement prior to Exec SPName and when calling SP along with Insert Into SomeTable prior Statement then SP is not getting called.

Comment: If you're saying that the executed of the batch terminates at the call to `USP_Reconcile_InsertUpdate` when it is it preceded by an `INSERT` statement, then the reason will be due to an error you are receiving and the batch is aborting. Inspect the error and if you don't understand it, post it.

Comment: @Larnu, if you have notice that in 3rd SP I have put the insert call to temp table to identify if there is an error or not, but nothing is inserted into Temp Table so doubt is when I put Insert Into prior to Exec SPName, that SP is NOT getting Called

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... EXEC` is perfectly valid syntax, @Mihir. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=15944c5a813e180449a75ba5ec215831)

Comment: @Larnu, Yes that is what my concern is, syntax is correct then where is the issue?, Is it due to Try-Catch OR is it due to Transaction in Nested SP?

Comment: Nested transactions are a myth, @MihirShah , they don't exist.

Comment: Your third procedure ultimately produces no results that can be inserted, unless that's in a block you left out as "return result". There is an `INSERT` statement in there, not a `SELECT`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I have just edited the code of 3rd SP, Select Statement is there. You might interpreted wrong due to Single Line Insert....Select Statement before Edited

Comment: That's clearer, yes. I go back to lurking.